# 2 routers, 2 subnets?

Tags: routing, subnet

Firstly I will explain why I require this setup. I have bought an ASICMiner Cube for mining Bitcoin. It frequently stops mining until I reset it, which is quite troublesome. After reading the troubleshooting here it says "My Cube mines for a bit, but then stops until reset: Take all android phones/tablets OFF the wifi, they interfere for some reason." Another requirement of the Cube is is MUST be on subnet 192.168.1.x

I have the following hardware... 1 x Belkin N600 DB Wi-Fi Dual-Band N+ Router 2 x Dynalink RTA1025W - ADSL2+ Wireless Modem Router

The Belkin is the main router. Is it possible to have it on the subnet 192.168.2.1, with DCHP enabled so that my housemates can use the internet as usual using that router, then have the Dynalink on the 192.198.1.1 subnet that I will use for the cube?

I need it so the computers on the different subnets can't communiciate, but both subnets need internet access. At the moment I have no internet on my 192.168.1.1 subnet (Dynalink) however the main Belkin router (192.168.2.1) is working fine.

Sorry if this is explained poorly, I have very limited networking skills.

Answer (score 0):

The WAN interface of your Dynalink must be connected to a LAN port on the router.

Connecting a LAN port on the Dynalink to a LAN port on the Belkin won't work.*

> 2 x Dynalink RTA1025W - ADSL2+ Wireless Modem Router

I'm betting this router only has a DSL jack for a WAN interface.  You need a router that has an Ethernet port for a "WAN" (labeled "Internet" on most routers) interface for this to work.

UPDATE: Seems from below your router does support VLANs and a WAN on the Ethernet.  Interesting.

Try manually setting the WAN / Ethernet1 IP to 192.168.2.200 or something else outside of your Belkin's DHCP range.  It's LAN IP needs to remain 192.168.1.1.

---

*It would if you could put the port that the Dynalink is connected in a different VLAN than the rest, and have the router work with VLANs.  There's a small chance you can to do this if you can flash all devices to DD-WRT, but you are probably better off finding an old Linksys WRT54G or similar that has a WAN Ethernet port.

Comment: I think y Dynalink RTA1025W can support VLANs http://puu.sh/71HYZ.png is my config page. When I plug in the Belkin router (192.168.2.1) to the LAN1 of the Dynalink router (192.168.1.1) I get no internet from that router/subnet. 

If you can help with what next steps to take that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On your Belkin,

Connect WAN port to whatever gets you to the internet

Configure Belkin:

```
LAN: 192.168.2.1
```

Configure wifi for your housemates

On your Dynalink (you only need one),

connect the WAN port to the Belkin LAN1

Configure Dynalink:

```
WAN: 192.168.2.200
LAN: 192.168.1.1
```

Connect your ASICMiner Cube to Dynalink

Answer (score 0):

If your Dynalink is connected to a phone line from your wall, it's acting as both a modem (which operates on OSI layer 1) and a router (which operates on OSI layer 3) two-in-one device. The modem brings the Internet to you house. The router portion connects the Internet to your home network.

Here's the hardware setup: telephone cable connects between the phone jack in your wall and the WAN port in the Dynalink. Now plug in an Ethernet cable between a LAN port in the Belkin and the WAN port on your Belkin router.

Now, computers connected to your Dynalink will be in one subnet and computers connected to your Belkin will be in another if you set it up correctly.

For the subnet configuration part, try this: http://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=132275#b. If both subnets don't get internet access, try power cycling your routers one at a time.

Here's another example of a simple 2-subnet home network: [Practical (not theoretical) Subnetting 192.168.0.0/25](https://superuser.com/questions/1075004/practical-not-theoretical-subnetting-192-168-0-0-25/1075044?noredirect=1#comment1517367_1075044)

If you want hosts in one subnet to be able to ping hosts in another, you can do this by setting up static routes.